# Capitalizing first letter in split-append-join operation

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
def pig(text):

    message = text.split()
    pig_latin = []

    for word in message:
        word = word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay'
        pig_latin.append(word)

    return ' '.join(pig_latin)

def main():
    
    user = str(input("Enter a string: "))
    print(f"Pig latin: {pig(user)}")
```

Input: `Practice makes perfect`

Expected Output: `Racticepay akesmay erfectpay`

My translator is working fine, but I need to capitalize only the first letter of every sentence.

I can't figure out where to place the `.capitalize()` to get my desired output. I have put it in many locations and no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @BrokenBenchmark said, a format string and a generator expression would simplify your code down to a single, readable line of code.

```
def pig(text):
    return ' '.join(f"{w[1:]}{w[0]}ay" for w in text.split()).capitalize()
```

Answer (score 0):

Capitalizing should be the last thing you do before you return, so put `.capitalize()` at the `return` statement.

Change

```py
return ' '.join(pig_latin)
```

to

```py
return ' '.join(pig_latin).capitalize()
```

Comment: Thats what I thought, but this is what I get.                                                                      
`Enter a string: Practice makes perfect`
`Pig latin: racticePay akesmay erfectpay`

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue you're describing.

Comment: Okay probably something wrong with my code then idk. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Just had to restart VS code now it works lol